# как перехватить трафик браузера (request headers)?

Tags: c#, .net, сеть

Мне нужно перехватить, получить request headers. Например, если вы нажмете на какую нибудь кнопку на сайте или обновите, отправляется запрос POST/GET.
[image: Демонстрация POST запроса]
Запрос в себе содержит response headers, request headers, и т д. Но мне нужно только получить request headers. Я пишу программу на c#, как я могу реализовать эту задачу на языке c#?
Читал, кто то говорит можно использовать proxy, я не нашел примеров к сожалению.
Буду благодарен за любую подсказку, помощь и т д.

Comment: Для перехвата трафика есть специальный софт - Fiddler или WireShark. Не надо ничего этого писать, всё уже написано.

Comment: @eapot, да, с вами согласен на счёт программ, так же есть неплохая программа http debugger. Но там все отслеживается вручную и т д. Чтобы что то посмотреть, самому нужно искать, исследовать и т д. Моя задача поймать определенный запрос, изменить какие то данные, заголовки и по новой этот запрос отправить. Программы к сожалению мне не помогут скорее(

Comment: То есть вы настолько досконально изучили вопрос, что наверняка знаете, что из того что я выше перечислил, ничего не поможет? Ну тогда вы разбираетесь в вопросе лучше меня.

Comment: Если найдешь старые версии FiddlerCore, когда оно еще было бесплатным - то через API  к нему можно работать с перехватываемым траффиком.